# PHP adds unecessary index to JSON

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I have the following JSON stored in a MongoDB collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("bbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaa998a50"),
    "client" : "1",
    "services" : [ 
            {
                    "minutes" : 30,
                    "label" : "Service 30"
            }, 
            {
                    "minutes" : 60,
                    "label" : "Service 60"
            }
    ],
    "status" : "Active",
    "lastModifiedOn" : ISODate("2016-01-14T12:17:08.780Z"),
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-01-14T12:17:08.780Z"),
// ...
```

}

And I am only passing certain values to the website:

```
$catalog['services'] = $databaseCatalog->services;
$catalog['status'] = $databaseCatalog->status;
```

Passed as JSON using:

```
var catalog = <?php echo json_encode($catalog) ?>;
```

Which than leads to unintended indexes:

```
var catalog = {"services":{"0":{"minutes":30,"label":"Service 30"}, ,"1":{"minutes":60,"label":"...
```

**QUESTION: Where is this index ("0", "1") coming from and how can I prevent from happening?**

The var dump as requested:

```
array (size=1)
    'services' => 
        object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)[47]
            public 0 => 
            object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)[40]
                public 'minutes' => int 30
                public 'label' => string 'Service 30' (length=10)
            public 1 => 
            object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)[41]
                public 'minutes' => int 60
                public 'label' => string 'Service 60' (length=10)
```

Comment: because services is an array itself those are the keys

Comment: what is in `$catalog->services`? Plus, if `$catalog` is an object, then you shouldn't be treating it as an array: `$catalog[arrayversion] = $catalog->objectversion` should raise warnings. either "canot use object as array" or "trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Post var_dump($catalog)

Comment: The extra indexes are due to the numeric indexes of the services array. It's a bit weird because JSON_FORCE_OBJECT isn't being passed to json_encode, but this is the behaviour.

Comment: I did a simple test, and works like you expected. `$str = '{
    "_id" : "bbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaa998a50",
    "client" : "1",
    "services" : [ 
            {
                    "minutes" : 30,
                    "label" : "Service 30"
            }, 
            {
                    "minutes" : 60,
                    "label" : "Service 60"
            }
    ],
    "status" : "Active"
}';
$obj = json_decode($str);`

Comment: I can't reproduce unless JSON_FORCE_OBJECT is specified: https://3v4l.org/cuTIC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the fact that MongoDB provides an object which, once mapped to an array generates the indexes.

The solution is to use the following approach:

```
$catalog['services'] = array_values((array)$databaseCatalog->services);
$catalog['status'] = array_values((array)$databaseCatalog->status);
```

Comment: OMG, I've just spent hours trying to find out how to easily convert a MongoDB object which contains an ArrayObject into a PHP array.  That "(array)" cast did the trick!!! Thank you!